# Javascript innerHTML Not Posting

Tags: javascript, html, posting

I am trying to get a function to print out whatever the user inputs into the text-box. I am using onClick as an attribute on my submit button. I know I set it up properly because it flickers the answer, but only for a split second. How can I get the input to stay on the page? Here's the code: HTML: Type what you want to post to the website!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main_div">
<section id="leftbox">
<form name="mybox">
    Type what you want to post to the website!:
    <br />
    <input type="textbox" size="15" maxlength="15" name="text"     id="text">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" onClick="doFirst()">
</form>
</section>
</div>
<div id="insert"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function doFirst(){
    text = document.getElementById('text');
   insert = document.getElementById('insert');     
  if(text.value == "")
  { 
    insert.innerHTML = "Please input something!";
    return false; 
  }
  else
  { 
    insert.innerHTML = text.value; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: use return true; in else condition.

Comment: See my answer below, and by the way, I think that you should change the question to "Javascript event not aborting form post" to better fit the scenario.  innerHTML has nothing to do with the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
Using type=button

```
<input type="button" value="Submit!" onClick="doFirst()">
```

OR using type=submit

```
<form name="mybox" onsubmit="doFirst(); return false;">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

Explain:

The action for `onclick` in submit button **DO** executed. You keep see the page does not have any changes, because of there are a **FORM**. And the key point: the form handle the submit action after the JS function `doFirst()` immediately. Adding the `onsubmit` in the form with `return false` to stop default action, means:

```
<form name="mybox" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="button" value="Submit!" onClick="doFirst()">
</form>
```

To simplify the changes, use button instead of submit type, or using onsubmit instead of onclick in form trigger.

Comment: Thank you so much! This did it! Never knew that "submit" and "button" could make the difference! Thank you :)

Comment: in addition: the attributes like 'onclick' should be lowercased (think internet explorer don't like them in camelcase)

Comment: Allen, for a more comlpete answer you should explain more about what the difference between `button` and `submit`

Comment: @TheHe the lower case and or upper case will not affect the most major browsers (Chrome, FF, IE9), but according to W3C, using `onclick` is most correct. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3

Comment: @JonP, added the button, form, onclick & onsubmit detail explain

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick="doFirst()"
```

gets converted into an anonymous function:

```
function(){ doFirst() }
```

and whatever that function returns determines if the submit should be completed or aborted, so you should use:

```
onClick="return doFirst();"
```

In other words, it's not enough that doFirst return something, whatever doFirst returns should be returned again inside the onClick.